# Xcode IB: Replace button with another type?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

In my Xcode project, I have a few buttons in the main window that I would like to replace with another type of button. In this case, there are a few rectangles and a rounded rectangle button. Is there an easy way to replace the buttons with another style, or am I stuck with deleting them and settings them all up again? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select button type custom and use your own special background as the button in Interface Builder.
If you want to further customize your button, I suggest making an outlet of it and customize it programmatically.

Good Luck!

Comment: Okay, thanks! While I was awaiting an answer, I did it the "delete-and-replace" way, but thanks for the answer!